# Fail to scrap the text located in such case but others work?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I was building scrapper to get the information of products.

I would like the get the description text about delivery as shwon in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3at3S.png) (Sorry reputation is not high enough to add pictures yet). The text highlighted in blue is the desired information to obtain. The code I am using is

```
reg = wait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "pns-product-pickup")))
methods = wait(reg, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.delivery-options")))
delivery=''
    
for method in methods:
    method1 = method.text
    info = wait(method, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.option-tips"))).text
    delivery=delivery+method1+info+'\n'

print(delivery)
```

The result I get is

```
Home Delivery
Click & Collect
```

Which means all the 'info' I add to 'delivery' is empty text, only 'method1' did return something.

I was wondering if it is the case that, the text I want is not shown on web unless I hold the mouse on the icon next to 'home delivery' like I was doing in the screenshot. Yet it is just a random guess and probably make no sense. Any idea of what might be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share the url of the page please

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar  here it is parknshop.com/en/full-cream-evaporated-milk/p/BP_491777

Comment: So you want `FULL CREAM EVAPORATED MILK` ub that page right?

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to access the delivery info, if you navigate to that element first (hover over it). THe following will get the home delivery info:

```
### chromedriver setup for linux
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

actions = ActionChains(browser)

url='https://parknshop.com/en/full-cream-evaporated-milk/p/BP_491777'
browser.get(url)

t.sleep(5) 
pns_more_info = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "pns-more-information")))
actions.move_to_element(pns_more_info)
actions.perform()
tips = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='option-tips']")))
print(tips.text)
```

This will print out:

```
Free delivery on orders above $500. For orders below $500, delivery fee of $50 shall apply
```

Do not forget to import `ActionChains`.